# How to reset keystores when you do not know their password?

Tags: java, keytool, android-keystore

For some reason I got this message:

`keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`

I know that I cannot "repair" the keystore, but I want to reset the keystore, but don't know how to do it, especially because I do not know the location of the default keystores.

Note: I just want the "blank" them so I restart from default. Still I wasn't even able to detect their location.

How can I list default keystores and their locations with keytool or something similar?

Comment: Keystores are designed for security, this is not going to be easy.

Comment: The whole point of the keystores is that if you don't know the master pasword you can't access the keys. Being able to reset the password would be pointless and not possible by requirement.

Answer (score 8):

Just remove `~/.keystore` file, which is the default keystore location.

Comment: Just to confirm... if you remove the keystore file you will need to import all your certs again. But at least you will be able to set it to the password you want.