# Android app Keystore password reset

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

How to reset **Keystore** password for android. I can't update application on play store.
How to resolve this problem?
When I tried to update the application with the new key then play store rejected it.
I have the old **Keystore** file but the password is not accepting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614407/how-to-reset-keystores-when-you-do-not-know-their-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Forgot keystore password. Can I decrypt keystore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894987/android-forgot-keystore-password-can-i-decrypt-keystore-file)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystore-password-recovery

Answer (score 0):

**Faced the same problem**

> You can create a new keystore, but the Android Market wont allow you
>   to upload the APK as an update - worse still, if you try uploading the
>   apk as a new app it will not allow it either as it knows there is a
>   'different' version of the same apk already in the market even if you
>   delete your previous version from the play store.

***Generally, the only advise that exists on keystores: "always back it up!"***

Or you may try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889605/8511061).

Answer (score 0):

I use this one for bruteforce at the moment: [Android keystore password recover](http://maxcamillo.github.io/android-keystore-password-recover/)

> There are 3 Methods to recover your keystore password:
>
> ```
> - Simply Bruteforce
> - Dictionary Attack
> - Smart Wordlist Attack
> ```

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

Useful links:

- http://www.icaninfotech.com/android-keystore-password-recovery/
- https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/forgot-android-alias-key-password/1873
- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1094759/Reset-keystore-password-without-entering-old-passw

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is here you can get your password from android studio.I windows go to

```
C:\Users\yourUser\.Android2.2\system\log\idea.log.1
```

where Android2.2 is the studio version , you have to go to your version name folder.  The password is shown just below the first ***** part . Search in file **** or **android.injected.signing.store** word. you will find your password.

Hope it helps to you.